# Android DES Decrypt badpaddingexception: pad block corrupted

Tags: android, encryption, des

First of all, I've reviewed all the entries on the forum, and I still can not find a solution to my problem.
I have to measure the time it takes to encode and decode a text with DES, and make a comparison with other algorithms.

When I run the code, I have this error: **BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted**. When I debug, the code fails in this line:

*byte [] plaintext = cipher.doFinal (cipherBytes);*

I use class Base64 to encode/decode String <--> byte[]

Any idea?

thanks

```
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
private static int KEY_LENGTH = 64;

 public static SecretKey deriveKeyDES() {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            kgen.init(KEY_LENGTH);
            SecretKey result = kgen.generateKey();

            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            return result;

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }


    public static String encrypt(String plaintext, SecretKey key) {
        try {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

            return toBase64(cipherText);

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String toBase64(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP).trim();
    }


    public static String decrypt(String ciphertext, SecretKey key) {
        try {
            byte[] cipherBytes = fromBase64(ciphertext);

                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            cipher.update(cipherBytes);

             // This is where I get exception
            byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);

            String plainrStr = new String(plaintext, "UTF-8").trim();
            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

            return plainrStr;
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] fromBase64(String base64) {
        return Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Comment: on a side note i would n't suggest you throw exception or use system.exit in you app since this will be unusal behaviour. rather catch the exception to avoid force-closes ...

Comment: Please post the actual main loop too, it's very likely that it contains the error.

Comment: Could you please follow up on your questions Elma?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
cipher.update(cipherBytes);

// byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
//                                   ^-- You shouldn't pass cipherBytes twice.
//                                   v-- instead use the parameter-less method:
byte[] plaintext    = cipher.doFinal();
```

Comment: I voted this up because it clearly indicates a mistake, but for ECB mode it certainly would not throw a `BadPaddingException`.

Answer (score 1):

Padding exception occur when the last cipher text block does not compute to valid plain text. This would happen if last ciphertext block is corrupted or the key is incorrect. For CBC mode it would also happen if the second to last ciphertext was altered (but you are using ECB mode encryption).

In your case, the `deriveKeyDES()` is always generating a random key. Although we didn't get the actual calls to the security methods, I would *presume* you use a different key for encryption and decryption. In that case there is a very high chance that the resulting plain text does not contain valid padding bytes.

Rasmus answer certainly points to an error in your code, and it would screw up your timings and return a the plain text two times, but it would not remove the `BadPaddingException`.

Comment: Thank you for your support.
Rasmus, I tried the answer you provided, but it doesnt work.

Comment: I agree with owlstead that something happened with cipher text (last block or something! but I dont know what). I have already check that key is the same for encrypt and decrypt (I log the key passed to encrypt and decrypt and they fit in) but I still think error is in ciphertext becouse the byte size is not the same... could be the error in my function "toBase64"?
Details:
ENCRYPT FUNCTION
 String plaintext count 38 
 byte aux [] length 38
DECRYPT FUNCTION
 String ciphertext count 56??
 byte cipherbytes [] length 56

Comment: Maybe do i have to use SecureRandom to initialized the key?
I dont know what else do...

Comment: you were right! I used different keys for encrypt and decrypt!! Thank you very much for your help and interest!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one source code, and IllegalBlockSizeException in another one.
Solved this two problems by return encoding data like:

```
 public String encrypt(String input) {
    try {
        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] enc = encryptCipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
        // and problem was in return encoding. That's how i fixed it 
        return Base64.encodeToString(enc,Base64.DEFAULT);
        .....
          }
        }
```

Give u a code for decrypt:

```
 public String decrypt(String input) {
    try {
        byte[] dec = Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        //here had exception
        byte[] utf8 = decryptCipher.doFinal(dec);
        return new String(utf8,"UTF8");
    } catch (IOException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I should submit, that had BadPaddingException and IllegalBlockSizeException 
only in *decrypt method* ***byte[] utf8 = decryptCipher.doFinal(dec);*** (u had exeption in the same place: ***byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);***), but real wrong is in *encrypt method(return value)*

That's why i recommend u to use that code in *encrypt method*:

```
return Base64.encodeToString(enc,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

P.S Tried to a give full answer on your question.